# How can i import bulk products with CSV having 1 lakh in PHP

Tags: magento2, php

tried with below code and saved only 10k records, how can i import with batch size?

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
    
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];    
     if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
     {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
          while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
           {
             $sql = "INSERT into employeeinfo (emp_id,firstname,lastname,email,reg_date) 
                   values ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$getData[3]."','".$getData[4]."')";
                   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(!isset($result))
        {
          echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
              alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
              window.location = \"index.php\"
              </script>";    
        }
        else {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
            window.location = \"index.php\"
          </script>";
        }
           }
      
           fclose($file);  
     }
  }
```

Comment: How is this related to Magento?

Answer (score 0):

`$result` is always correct for every import.
Should be something like this.

````php
if (isset($_POST["Import"])) {

    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        // Set success default to false (if f.e. no rows exist)
        $success = false;
        while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 100000, ",")) !== false) {
            $sql = "INSERT into employeeinfo (emp_id,firstname,lastname,email,reg_date)
                   values ('" . $getData[0] . "','" . $getData[1] . "','" . $getData[2] . "','" . $getData[3] . "','" . $getData[4] . "')";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            
            // Set success to true of correct
            $success = isset($result);
        }

        if (!$success) {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
              alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
              window.location = \"index.php\"
              </script>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
            window.location = \"index.php\"
          </script>";
        }

        fclose($file);
    }
}```

By the way, please check PDO for secure insert, your code is risky.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
````